# All images from DB load into the first ListView Error

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I am extracting data from a DB, various strings and String representing Image Paths to Images in the  external directory.

My problem is when the list view loads all the images from the cursor object are loaded into the first list view, which is time consuming, and then each image is loaded correctly into subsequent view.

So my question is why is every image from the database been loaded into the first list view and not one image per list view  as required.

This is my Cursor adapter code, I load the images from the DB using a asynch task (apologies in advance its allot of code!).

Any input appreciated.

```
 @Override
        public void bindView(View v, Context context, final Cursor c) {


            /*
             * Binds the data from each row (stored in cursor object) to the ListView.xml
             * first free up List object if not in view of the screen by holding a ref to it, therefore dont
            * waste memeory and tiome recreating each view when out of viewable list to user
            */

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            String diveSite = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVESITE));
            holder.title_text.setText(diveSite);

            String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY__DIVEDATE));
            holder.date_text.setText(date);

            String rating = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVERATING));
            holder.bar.setNumStars(5);
            holder.bar.setRating( Float.parseFloat(rating));




            String diveNumber= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY__DIVENUMBER));


            String diveImagePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVEPICTURE));


            c.moveToLast();
            noOfRows = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(diveDataBase.KEY__DIVENUMBER)));
            holder.dive_no.setText(diveNumber+"/"+noOfRows);



            //set image here once taken form external string path, and resized bitmap conversion

            getImageAsynch = (getBitmapImage) new getBitmapImage(v).execute(diveImagePath);
```

Here is the asynch inner class where the image is taken from path to ext directory, resized, then populates the view holder...

class getBitmapImage extends AsyncTask{

```
            private View view;
            private ViewHolder holderB;
            public getBitmapImage(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub, takes ViewGroup as arg
                //ViewGroup parent;
                view=v;
                holderB=new ViewHolder();

        }





            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... imagePath) {

                /* 
                 * get image path and decode to bitmap
                *   First must make sure image loaded from DB base 64 is not loaed into memory 
                *   at full size ie 1028 * 800 pixels
                *   Instead we use BitMapOptions object methods inJustDecodeBounds 
                *   to stop autoloading of image, 
                *   then we scale down the image for loading into memory using 
                *   BitMapOPtiontions.inSampleSize method
                *   This will significantly reduce memory usage and time req to load images into list view
                *
                *    first check if user wants to preview images (boolean displayImagesUserChoice), if not return null, 
                *   this value is passed from dialog propmt in ViewListOfDives
                *   and passed to ItemAdpter constructor
                */


                if(displayImagesUserChoice){

                if(!isCancelled()){
                String diveImagePath = imagePath[0];

                 File imagePathFile = new File(diveImagePath); 
                 try {
                    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 3000;
                        FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(imagePathFile);

                    // Decode image size and setInJBounds = true to avoid auto memory allocation for large image
                        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                       BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn, null, o);
                         streamIn.close();

                        -----allot of resizing image code here have removed for an easier read---

                         streamIn.close();
                         b.recycle();
                         System.gc();

                } else {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn);
                   resizedImage = reSizeImage(bitmap);
                  streamIn.close();
                 noOfImagesloaded++;
                   System.gc();
                }

                        //resizedImage = reSizeImage(bitmap);


                 }catch(IOException exe){
                     exe.printStackTrace();



            }catch(OutOfMemoryError exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong! Try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch(NullPointerException nullpoint){
                nullpoint.printStackTrace();
                //end try catch
            }


                }//end if anstch class notCancelled from the onCakPressed method of viewListOfDives
                else if(isCancelled()){
                    Log.d("ItemAdpter Aycnh", "Do in background cancelled");
                }

                Log.d("ItemApdter Aycnh", "No of Images loaded = "+  noOfImagesloaded);
                //return bitmap;

                }//end if displayImagesUserChoice=true, if not true resizedIMage is returned as null to onPostExecute

                return resizedImage;
            }//end do in background


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

                //intilise holder to listview.xml ImageView
                holderB.displayImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_image); //image view
                //ImageView displayImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_image);
                if(bitmap!=null ){

                    //set image using holder static object

                    holderB.displayImage.setBackground(null);

                    holderB.displayImage.setImageBitmap(resizedImage);

                }else{


                    //set default image using static holder object

                    holderB.displayImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera4);
                }

            }//end onPOstExecute
        }//end getBitmap asynch
```

Answer (score 0):

The view holder containing text views and rating bar returns faster than the image , which is taken from sd card asynchronously, so therefore there is delay in populating the view with image. Removing the loading of images asynchronously removes the problem but the GUI is unresponsive until all images are loaded, so no choice really but to use the asynchronous task.